# Residue Theorem: calculate the integral $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=3} \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2(z^2+2z+2)} dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus

Hi can i get a proof check please. Thanks
Define $|z|=3 \implies S$ ie denote the circle of radius 3 by S
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{S} \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2(z^2+2z+2)} dz = \\
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{S} \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2(z+1+i)(z+1-i)} dz = \\
W(S,0)Res(f,0)+W(S,-1+i)Res(f,-1+i)+W(S,-1-i)Res(f,-1-i)
\end{equation}

We have three poles, inside the circle of radius 3, 1 pole of order 2, and 2 simple poles. with the contour winding around each pole only once.

[image: Contour]

Calculating these i have

1. $z^2 = 0;$ A pole of Order 2: then let $\psi(z) = (z-0)^{2}\frac{e^{zt}}{z^2(z^2+2z+2)} = \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+2z+2}$ then
   $$Res(f,0) = \frac{1}{(2-1)!}\lim_{z \longrightarrow 0}\frac{d^{(2-1)}}{dz^{(2-1)}}(\psi(z))$$
   $$Res(f,0) = \lim_{z \longrightarrow 0}\psi'(z) = \lim_{z \longrightarrow 0}\frac{e^{zt}\left(tz^2+(2t-2)z+2t-2\right)}{(z^2+2z+2)^{2}} = \frac{t-1}{2}$$
2. $z=-1+i;$ A pole of Order 1: it's a simple pole then
   $$Res(f,-1+i) = \lim_{z \longrightarrow (-1+i)} \frac{(z+1-i)e^{zt}}{z^2(z+1+i)(z+1-i)}$$ 
   $$= \lim_{z \longrightarrow (-1+i)} \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2(z+1+i)} = \frac{e^{(i-1)t}}{4}$$
3. $z=-1-i;$ A pole of Order 1: it's a simple pole then
   $$Res(f,-1-i) = \lim_{z \longrightarrow (-1-i)} \frac{(z+1+i)e^{zt}}{z^2(z+1+i)(z+1-i)}$$ 
   $$= \lim_{z \longrightarrow (-1+i)} \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2(z+1-i)} = \frac{e^{-(i+1)t}}{4}$$
   \begin{equation}
   \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{S} \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2(z+1+i)(z+1-i)} dz = \\
   Res(f,0)+Res(f,-1+i)+Res(f,-1-i) = \\
   \frac{t-1}{2}+\frac{e^{(i-1)t}}{4}+\frac{e^{-(i+1)t}}{4} \implies \\
   \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{S} \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2(z+1+i)(z+1-i)} dz = \frac{2(t-1)+e^{(i-1)t}+e^{-(i+1)t}}{4}
   \end{equation}

Comment: Correct. As an observation, notice that this is the inverse Laplace transform of $1/(z^2 (z^2 + 2 z + 2))$.